# how do we compile and run a haskell program on terminal?

Tags: command-line, c

I have my program saved as prog.c

how do I compile it and run it?

Comment: What's with the [tag:c] tag and the `.c` file extension? Why aren't you using the [tag:haskell] tag and a `.hs` extension?

Comment: Maybe take a look here, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676331/how-to-run-a-haskell-file-in-interpreted-mode

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps

In short you start the haskell enviornment and load your program, then you run it like you would any other command `./prog`